# Autocorrelation Exponential Decay Rate for feature selection

Tags: pca, autocorrelation, signal-processing

I have signals of a time series of length 50.
I want to give a try to a PCA like method for classification extracting features from the signal. I am considering several summary descriptors (e.g, mean, var, range, ...). This work well for some of the categories but I still have a strong overalap. I would also like to extract parameters that describe the shape and autocorrelation seemed like a good candidate.

I was thinking of fitting an exponential model to each signal and passing the coefficient to the PCA. **My question is: how meaningful would this be? Maybe that coefficient makes no real sense.**

Here's a graph showing `acf` output for 3 of the categories I'm dealing with, just as an example of blue having faster decay that red/green. [image]